# a tag with onclick return false; still clickable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

I have a link:

```
<a id="trigger" href="file.pdf" onclick="return false;">Download pdf</a>
```

and this Javascript:

```
// Check validation and enable or disable the <a> tag
if( $('#input_1').hasClass('valid') )
{
    $('#trigger').prop("onclick", null);    
}
else // disable the button
{
    $('#trigger')[0].onclick = function () { return false; }
}
```

However when the validation fails the button still works even with the

```
onclick="return false;"
```

Can someone help me understand this and how to efficiently disable the anchor tag?

UPDATE: fixed  `$('#trigger')[0].onclick = function () { return false; }` but once this makes it to the anchor tag the button still serves the file download.

Comment: jQuery has no `onclick` method... read through the api events methods. Why are you using inline `onclick` in the first place?

Comment: @charlietfl woops, corrected. Also the anchor must load with an `onclick="return false;"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do either of the following:

```
$('#trigger')[0].onclick = function () {return false;}
```

or

```
$('#trigger').click(function () {return false;});
```

Comment: That is correct, however the anchor still downloads when clicked even with the onclick="return false;" set.

Answer (score 1):

```
if( $('#input_1').hasClass('valid') )
{
    $('#trigger').attr("onclick", null);    
}
else // disable the button
{
    $('#trigger').on('click', function(e) { e.preventDefault(); } );
}
```

Better use `.preventDefault` method. 
Also use `.prop` method only for form controls.

Comment: "Use .prop method only for form controls" is a bit misleading – `.prop()` should be used for properties. Manipulating/accessing form element properties is a common use case but it doesn't mean it's the *only* use case.

Comment: True, it's not only usable for form controls, but I think it is more intuitive to debug, for someone who is working after you.

Answer (score 1):

For cases like this, I like to make it a tad harder for people to by-pass the front-end security. (But only a little but, obviously this can easily be by-passed.)

1. Call event.preventDefault() if not valid
2. Add class to element if not valid. This class will have `pointer-events` set to none so it won't register clicks
3. Check if a global JS variable has been set

```js
var valid = false;

$("#valid-checkbox").change(function() {
  var $this = $(this),
    trigger = $("#trigger");

  if ($this.is(":checked")) {
    valid = true;
    $this.val("valid");
    trigger.removeClass("disabled");
  } else {
    valid = false;
    $this.val("invalid");
    trigger.addClass("disabled");
  }
});

$("#trigger").click(function(e) {
  if (valid === false || $(this).hasClass("disabled") || $("#valid-checkbox").val() == "invalid") {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

```css
.disabled {
  opacity: 0.5;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="trigger" href="http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image1.jpg" class="disabled" target="_blank">Download pdf</a>

<input type="checkbox" value="invalid" id="valid-checkbox">
<label for="valid-checkbox">Valid?</label>
```